# Which RxJava operator for this usecase

Tags: android, rx-java

This is a scenario I'm having. I've two methods

1. getCachedData(): Single<Optional>
2. getRemoteData(): Single<Data>

Now what I want to know is how to write a function like `getData(): Single<Custom>`, which will fetch this Custom data from cache. If the cache doesn't have it, I would like to fetch the same from remote. I also don't want to use multiple subscription.

p.s. I've seen many examples of doing this, but in almost all of the cases the problem is, the data is fetch from both of the sources. And the first emitted item is used (combineLatest).

Comment: i think [mayBe](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Maybe.html) will do the job .

Comment: It might be done on the cache level. You pass a lambda for fetching remote data into the cache which, in its turn, is looking if it "has" the data. If it does, it just returns the cached data, otherwise, it invokes the lambda and "stores" the response.